# C# - New thread does not start

Tags: c#, multithreading

I would like to ask you why is my method StartReading is not triggered? I expected "test" text in console but nothing appeared.

```
public class Connection
{
    public List<byte[]> ReadBuffer = new List<byte[]>();

    TcpClient ClientLogin;
    NetworkStream StreamLogin;
    DataEncoder NetworkBufferLogin;

    Thread ReadingThread;

    public Connection()
    {
        ClientLogin = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        StreamLogin = ClientLogin.GetStream();
        NetworkBufferLogin = new DataEncoder(StreamLogin);
        ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading);
    }

    private void StartReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            byte[] a = NetworkBufferLogin.ReceiveData();
            ReadBuffer.Add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

and simple calling

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Connection test = new Connection();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider starting the thread with its Start() method.

Comment: Instead of threading, use asynchronouse Stream methods, eg [Stream.ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx). Asynchronous network methods offload the work to the OS and don't consume any threads, resulting in much better performance and simpler, safer code

Comment: To downvoters, typos are a reason to close, not downvote! Downvotes are for bad questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not a C# guru but I think you need to call `Thread.Start()`:

```
 public Connection()
    {
        ClientLogin = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
        StreamLogin = ClientLogin.GetStream();
        NetworkBufferLogin = new DataEncoder(StreamLogin);
        ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading);
        ReadingThread.Start();
    }
```

Anyway, using a single thread for a single connection is a **very** bad idea. you should probably use asynchronous IO (which is remarkably simple and handy with TPL and `async`/`await` keywords, kudos, .Net), or at least use a threadpool.

you should think as your program as a business and creation of thread as hiring a new worker. would you hire and fire a whole new worker for each task your business requires? of course not. you should hire a few workers and make them work on the tasks that your business requires.

Comment: ahhh of course you are right ... just stupid forgotten

Comment: @ErikŠťastný the real answer is the second paragraph. Don't use threads. Use Stream.ReadAsync and async/await. Network operations don't use threads to wait, they are *alreay* asynchronous. In fact, the OS has to emulate synchronous IO by blocking the calling thread

Comment: yep+ but i have no idea what this method doing i need to check it first :)

Comment: if i understand it correctly the Anync method work same like normal read method but not freezing the thread?

Comment: @ErikŠťastný exactly. than you can use a small number of threads and make them work on new connections or continue working on old connections when the IO finishes.

Comment: ok i have got first issue Async is from .net 4.5 i have 2.0 :/

Comment: you do you only have .Net 2.0? just upgrade you project

Comment: yep because its part of another framework which have support only .net 2.0

Comment: you still have `Stream.BeginRead` and `Stream.EndRead` which available since .Net 1.1. less fun than `ReadAsync` but still utilizes asynchronous IO

Comment: You are right, i will have to study how to use them :) I have no idea what one of the paremeter "AsyncCallback callback" means for example

Comment: can i ask you for example of using mentioned method?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start the thread:

```
public Connection()
{
    ClientLogin = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);
    StreamLogin = ClientLogin.GetStream();
    NetworkBufferLogin = new DataEncoder(StreamLogin);
    ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading);
    ReadingThread.Start(); // <- here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need invoke method "Start()".

```
 ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading);
 ReadingThread.Start();
```

I also recommend doing the background tread.

```
ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading) {IsBackground = true};
ReadingThread.Start();
```

this will help to avoid a freeze program upon completion of the main tread.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadingThread = new Thread(StartReading);
ReadingThread.Start(); // to start your thread
ReadingThread.Stop(); // to stop your thread
ReadingThread.Sleep(2000); // to sleep(miliseconds) your thread
```

Comment: I think **Thread.Sleep(int)** is a static method used inside of the thread in which you want to perform sleep operation. Like `new Thread( () => { while(true) { Thread.Sleep(1000); } } ).Start();` So it cannot be used as an instance member function.